# Getting form data in Django middleware

Tags: python, django

What I am basically trying to do is capture data into my middleware from front end, so that I can track the users activity. User activity refers to buttons clicked and data entered into a form.
So I am done with the button part but stuck on getting data filled in the form by the user. I need help with that.

Below is my html and my middleware build in python:

**middleware.py:**

```
class TodoappMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        if request.method == "GET":
            f = open("/home/gblp250/Desktop/log", 'a')
            f.write("User clicked ")
            name = request.GET.get('name')
            if not name == 'None':
                f.write(str(name))
                f.write("\n")
            f.close()

        elif request.method == 'POST':
            f = open("/home/gblp250/Desktop/log", 'a')
            f.write("User clicked ")
            if request.POST.get("Login"):
                nm = request.POST.get("Login")
                if not nm == 'None':
                    f.write("Login\n")
            elif request.POST.get("Authorize"):
                f.write("Authorize\n")
            elif request.POST.get("Assign"):
                f.write("Assign\n")
            elif request.POST.get("delete_task"):
                f.write("Delete task\n")
            elif request.POST.get("mark_complete"):
                f.write("Mark as complete\n")
            elif request.POST.get('authorise_users'):
                form = AuthUserCheckbox(request.POST)
                if form.is_valid():
                    ch = form.cleaned_data.get('choice')
                    print "User then chose "
                    f.write(ch)

            f.close()
```

**html:**

```
{% extends 'todoapp/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Authorize users{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h2>Select users to authorize</h2>
    <form method="post" action="{% url 'auth_users' %}" id="authorise_users">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.choice }}
        <br/><input type="submit" value="Authorize" name="Authorize">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;<button onclick="location.href='{%url 'dashboard' %}?name=Go back'" type="button">Go back</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

All the `request.POST.get` are buttons except for `authorise_users`, it is a checkbox. I am not able to get the user entered value for that. All buttons clicks I have got but I am not able to get the selected value for `authorise_users`

Comment: You have to tell us whats wrong. What is the error you are getting? Were are you stuck? Does it write to the file at all?

Comment: Its not writing to the file. It'll write that user went to the intended page but not the choices he made. Error i am getting is `AttributeError at /auth_users/

'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'choice`

Comment: have you tried `print(request.POST)` and `print(form.cleaned_data)` to see what values it actually contains? Maybe it contains something different than you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you are getting (mentioned in a comment to the question), you probably need to change the line

```
if request.choice.is_valid():
```

to

```
if form.choice.is_valid():
```

or

```
if form.is_valid():
```

Does that help to solve the error?

Comment: Also, you are not closing your file at the end of the middleware. That is not a good idea. Maybe use `with open(...` to avoid that kind of easily overlooked mistake.

Comment: I have placed my `form = AuthUserCheckbox(data=request.POST, user=request.user)` in `Authorize`. Is that correct or do I need to create a new `request.POST.get` elif branch for it ?

Comment: Remember that `if request.POST.get("Login")` and `elif request.POST.get("Authorize")` will be `True` if the value retrieved from `request.POST` evaluates to `True`. Maybe you need to do a bit stricter checking, for example `if request.POST.get("Login") == 'something'`.

Comment: that's right. Based on this only I've detected all the button clicks but I am not able to get the data entered by the user in a form. Any help with that ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you add more info in your question, for example some outputs of print statements before the parts that do not seem to be working? (comments are not the right place to add a lot of info, because they have only limited formatting)

Comment: I will edit the question so you get a better idea of what I am trying to do

Comment: Edited the question. Kindly have a look at it.